# Laravel image upload optimizer package issue

Tags: laravel

->When I uplaod large image greater than 4 MB in laravel using "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.3", package error

Error :

InvalidArgumentException
`` does not exist
vendor\spatie\image-optimizer\src\Image.php

use InvalidArgumentException;

class Image
{
    protected $pathToImage = '';

```
public function __construct(string $pathToImage)
{
    if (! file_exists($pathToImage)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("`{$pathToImage}` does not exist");
    }

    $this->pathToImage = $pathToImage;
}

public function mime(): string
{
    return mime_content_type($this->pathToImage);
}

public function path(): string
{
    return $this->pathToImage;
}
```

Comment: Write part of code where/how do you use it. It seems you are not passing `$pathToImage`.

Comment: "$pathToImage" this my vendor package code..

Comment: If I uplaod less then 2 MB image no error generate

Comment: I asked you to show how do you use it in your code.

Comment: i uplaod more than 2MB image but not uploaded.

Comment: You are not reading what I am asking you. Edit your question with controller (or any class) code where `Image` is used in action.

Comment: I upload screenshot.Please check it   https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoDEJ.png

Comment: Do you understand what I ask you? Post code (not in comments though) where you are using this package. It's probably some of your controllers. Edit your question above and post that controller code (don't forget to format it in code tags). If you don't understand this simple request then I don't think anyone can help you with this.